# Tableau create one dimension by appending multiple dimensions

Tags: tableau-api

I have created 9 calculated fields that return the desired results.  Now I want to create a single dimension (or measure if more appropriate) that combines the fields into one by appending the data, not creating a combined string field.  I know I can do this in Excel very easily, but am at a loss in Tableau.  Please see screen shots for more information.

Pic 1- This is the code for each calculated field (only the number of minutes are changed).  > 75 also has an if statement attached.
[image]

Pic 2 - This is a combined field of all the data I want in one column.  This is validating that my calculation fields are returning the desired result.
[image]

The end goal is to create a single bar chart based on the combined data.  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Wait, what? You want to "append the data" from nine columns into one column by "not creating a combined string field"? Those are two distinctly contradictory statements. Can you clarify?

Comment: sure.  I have 9 columns with dates. I want to combine them into a single column that contains all the dates from those 9 columns.  I don't want the "combined field" that simply joins the columns the same way that `columns(1)  & ", " & columns(2)` would do in VBA.  So, if column(1) had 10 rows (Jan1-10) and column(2) had 20 rows(Jan11-30), I would want my combined column to have 30 rows (Jan1-Jan30).  Is that a little clearer?

Comment: Gotcha. What you want to do is temporal analysis. I attended a class at Tableau Conference 2017 a few weeks ago showing how to do this. Let me see if I can put together some screenshots for you showing how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but get the feeling what you want to achieve can be done by dragging the "Measure Values" into your visualization, and then the "Measure Names" into color, or whatever else. You can filter on "Measure Names" to include only those measures you created, and they will be represented as one pill, but will include all of the values and retain them as individual measures.

Comment: unfortunetly, the date dimensions are not measures.  I think I am going to need to come at this from a different angel.  I will start another thread.  Thanks